# Jquery tabs update tab after form submit in the same tab

Tags: jquery

I have a page with 6 tabs (Jquery tabs) and on each tab there is a form. I looks like a simple question, but i'm breaking my head on it.
I want to update the div (tab) after `submit` of the form, after the `submit` there are of course also some actions (database update).

```
<form name="prijzen_huidige_jaar" method="post" action="<?php $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] ?>">
```

Comment: If you mean you want for the page to not refresh, you could either submit into an iframe or use an AJAX form submission.

Comment: `POST`ing to `PHP_SELF` would cause the page to reload. Your best bet is to `POST` to a separate PHP file using `$.ajax` and loading the resulting data into a DOM element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start by something like that:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.form-to-submit').submit(function(){ // a class to give all your forms
    content = $(this).serialize();
    $.post('/path/to/script.php', content, function(data){
      if(data){ 
        // The script returned something in the "data" variable. Do things like:
        $('container').replaceWith(data);
      }
    });
  })
});
```

Comment: If i use a separate script to do the form actions, does the form than "reload" so i can use the $_POST variables to display, so i don't have to retrieve the data from the database?

Comment: you can user your form action script to return a JSON object in PHP. The $.post function will get that object in the `if(data){ }` loop, and you'll be able to use the variables there directly.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the changes via ajax?

If yes... you could use success event to do your changes.

```
$.post(Url , function(data){
}).success(function(data){
  //Here you could do another post call to get your new data 
  $.post(refreshUrl,function(dataRefresh){
     //Your refresh here
  });
});
```

Comment: how do jo mean getting changes via Ajax?